# How to remove the space from the comments in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

If I want to comment a block of code in Sublime Text 2 I can highlight the code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. The changes the code from looking like this:

```
var foo = 1;
// (start of highlight)
if (foo) {
    foo += 1;
}
// (end of highlight)
return foo;
```

to looking like this:

```
var foo = 1;

// if (foo) {
//     foo += 1;
// }

return foo;
```

However, when I comment things out of my code using `//` I never include the space afterward, I only include the space when the comment is an actual note. I find this much easier to differentiate a note to myself (or another developer) from commented out code.

My question is: **is there a setting in Sublime Text 2 that allows me to remove the space after the single line comment characters when I use the keyboard short cut?**

Comment: what language(s) are you working with? It looks like javascript, but I want to make sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commenting functionality is located in `Packages/Default/comment.py`, where `Packages` is the folder opened when selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. If you're up on your Python, you can go through the file and determine how the additional space is added at the beginning of the line. I'm still going through it now, so I don't have a definitive answer, but contrary to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118421/1426065) there should definitely be a way of doing it without writing a new plugin.

If I figure out a workaround I'll update this answer.

---

#### **UPDATE**

So, it turns out that you don't need to edit the `comment.py` file after all. It looks like you're working with JavaScript, which is good because the workaround is already there. Go to `Packages/JavaScript` and open `Comments.tmPreferences`, which is just a standard PLIST/XML file. It should look like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.js, source.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>// </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>/*</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>*/</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>A67A8BD9-A951-406F-9175-018DD4B52FD1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you look at the `TM_COMMENT_START` key, you'll see that it's set to `<string>// </string>`. Just remove the trailing space after the `//`, save the file, and restart Sublime for good luck. Now, when you're in JS files, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> will insert two forward slashes without a trailing space.

Comment: With Sublime being so configurable I figure there had to be a way. And yes, I am mainly working in JavaScript. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MattDMo I tried doing that with Sublime 3 and sublime does not reflect the change after restarting. I even deleted the `.cache` ones but nothing. Even  making the xml invalid by deleting random stuff, sublime didn't complained on the console. Is there other thing I could try?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL for ST3 you need to create the `Packages/JavaScript` directory and place `Comments.tmPreferences` inside it. The `Packages` directory needs to be the one opened when you go to the `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` menu. If that still doesn't work please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you open `Keybindings - Default` under the `Preferences` menu, you can see on line 242 ( in my sublime):

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
```

This means that the shortcut key `ctrl+/` is used for command `toggle_comment`.

From unofficial [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/commands.html?highlight=comment):

> "toggle_comment
>
> Comments or uncomments the active lines. block
>
> [Bool]: Whether to use a block comment."

Sublime is not open source so we cannot modify the behavior of a built-in command if the argument does not allow us to.

In conclusion, there is no such setting in sublime, but we can write our own package to achieve it.